# Outlook and messages in the outbox with delay delivery

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I had to send some emails on a schedule, and so used the *Delay Delivery* feature. It works for the most part, but when I

- opened one of the emails waiting to send, to check its scheduled delivery time,
- closed it (by pressing X, not send), and
- said *No* when asked if I wanted to save,

the delivery date cleared to "None" and the email didn't send automatically.

EDIT: To clarify, in the outbox, the delivery date said None (it used to say the time that I pressed send), but inside the message itself, the date was still saved.

Is this supposed to happen? It just seems like if you click that you don't want to save changes then it should still send on schedule as opposed to not sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think as you did, and I just did test this on Outlook 2010, and it behaved as we expected. Despite the save warning, which I dismissed, it did save my delivery time.

I would try another test e-mail, and see if it was just an anomaly with that one e-mail. If not, then you can start troubleshooting in earnest.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, my edit explains a bit. But I'll try that with a few more emails and see.

Comment: @Jamie I see now...Mine does that also. I just did a test to see if it will go off at 11 am...(almost 11...waiting)...It did NOT go. I tested this: When closing it, ALWAYS hit the Send button again, and it will work. Don't X out of it, and even hitting save will not make it go...only send. If this answer worked for you, I would appreciate it if you upvote and mark it as answered. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it helped, thanks. Though this just seems very non-intuitive, and I'm curious as to the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Jamie My opinion: Just a programming oversight. I doubt it was intentional.